# Unix timestamp keeps returning Jan 17 1970 in DateTime

Tags: java, android, jodatime

I am using the following method to return a formatted date as say `07:00AM, Apr 12 2016`. But I keep getting `01:41PM, Sat, Jan 17 1970`. Say for example my timestamp is `1460469600`.

Here is my method.

```
public static String formattedDate(long timestamp) {
    DateTime date = new DateTime(timestamp);
    String formatted= date.toString("hh:mma, EEE, MMM dd yyyy");
    return formatted;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your timeStamp is wrong. It doesnt represent the correct time in millis. YOur timeStamp refers to 01:41PM, Sat, Jan 17 1970.

You can check what time date the timeinmillis (TimeStamp) refers to from this site.

http://currentmillis.com/

To get the correct time from unix time stamp just change your DateTime date = new DateTime(timestamp); into

```
    DateTime date = new DateTime(timestamp*1000);
```

Because unix time gives timpestamp in seconds and we need millis here.

Comment: This seems to work but i'm getting a two hour shift, for example : 1590516000 is 26.05.2020 18:00, tested on : https://www.silisoftware.com/tools/date.php?inputdate=1590516000&inputformat=unix, but when multiplied by 1000 and formatted i get : 2020.05.26 20:00

Answer (score 1):

Query to get timestamp in milliseconds :

```
select  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(yourtimestamp) *1000  from tablename.
```

this gives  time stamp in milliseconds in mysql